# Get image from UIWebView using UIPasteboard

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uipasteboard

I'm trying to get copied image from `UIWebView` using `UIPasteboard`.

```
[_myWebView copy:[UIApplication sharedApplication]]; //Copy selection to general pasteboard

NSArray* types = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].pasteboardTypes];
NSLog(@"Type %@", [types objectAtIndex:0]);

if([[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] containsPasteboardTypes:UIPasteboardTypeListString]){

    NSLog(@"text selected %@",[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string);

}else if([[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] containsPasteboardTypes:UIPasteboardTypeListImage]){

    NSLog(@"image selected");

}else if ([[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] containsPasteboardTypes:UIPasteboardTypeListURL]){

    NSLog(@"url selected");
}
```

If I copy text it's ok, but if I copy an image I get:

```
WebController.m:445 > Type com.apple.rtfd
WebController.m:458 > text selected {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252
{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 .SFUIText-Regular;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red45\green45\blue45;}
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720\qc\partightenfactor0
\f0\fs32 \cf2 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0 \strokec2 \
}
```

I tried with many images from different websites, but I always get the type rtfd, that actually is rich text. Somebody could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

1) add a long press gesture to your web view

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longTap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:nil];
    longTap.delegate = self;
    [_myWebView addGestureRecognizer:longTap];
```

2)implement the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    NSLog(@"TAPPED");

    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) {

        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        NSString *imgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).src", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y];
        NSString *urlToSave = [_myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:imgURL];
        NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToSave];
        NSLog(@"image URL :%@",urlToSave);

        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        NSLog(@"Image:%.00fx%.00f",image.size.height,image.size.width);

        if (image != nil) {
            NSLog(@"image exist 1");
            _selectedImageDataAtPoint = imageData;

        }

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Where "_selectedImageDataAtPoint" is a class variable of type NSData to store data image if exist

3) check for data existence after selection inside the method you use to get text and image

```
[_myWebView copy:[UIApplication sharedApplication]]; //Copy selection to general pasteboard

    NSArray* types = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].pasteboardTypes];
    NSLog(@"Type %@", [types objectAtIndex:0]);

    if ([[types objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"com.apple.rtfd"]) {

        if ([UIImage imageWithData:_selectedImageDataAtPoint] != nil) {

            NSLog(@"image exist 2");
            _manualRecipe.imageData = _selectedImageDataAtPoint;
            [self openActivityWithImage];

        }

    }else if([[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] containsPasteboardTypes:UIPasteboardTypeListString]){

        NSLog(@"text selected: %@",[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string);
        NSString* text = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;
        [self openActivityWithText:text];

    }
```

The point is that for selecting text or image from web the user do a long press, so I add another UILongPressGestureRecognizer for getting image. After that I present my custom UIMenuItem to let the user save the selection.